# return two lists into html table using tabulate in python

Tags: python, html, django, list, html-table

I am new with html and I'm trying to display two lists into a table on the html page.

I can display the lists but can't get them to display as a nice table.

My code is:

```
from tabulate import tabulate 

def some_function(a, b, c)
    cols = ['Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col3']
    vals = [a, b, c]
    table = [cols, vals]
    table = tabulate(table, tablefmt='html')
    return table
some_function(1.01, 1.03, 1.05)
```

This returns the following html code:

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td>Col 1</td><td>Col 2</td><td>Col 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>1.01     </td><td>1.03      </td><td>1.05     </td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I am using Django so I can successfully return the html script to the website with my View but it doesn't read it as code, it appears as a string:

View:

```
 def post(self, request):
        form_c = CalculatorForm(request.POST, prefix='form_c')
        try:
            if form_c.is_valid():
                post = form_c.cleaned_data
                numbers = some_function(1.01, 1.03, 1.05)

        except:
            pass

        args = {
            'form_c': form_c, 'form_cols': numbers,
        }
        return render(request, self.template, args)
```

my html:

```
    <div class="container">
        {{ form_cols }} # <-- where I want my table
    </div>
```

Comment: This code looks fine. What do you mean by "nice table"?

Comment: what's the templating engine?

Comment: @anandogc I want that html code snippet to work in the html argument ‘form_cols’ but it returns the snippet as a string not acting like code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the html write (assuming default template engine):

```
    <div class="container">
        {{ form_cols|safe }}
    </div>
```